java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused processing IDE
hope you doing all well, i m using processing IDE to interact with arduinos chips scattered across the local network, so i did a client server architecture via ethernet, made sure each chips has its own unique and available ip adresse, when i tried to communicate with 3 chips it works well,  but the moment i exceed 3 chips simultaniously i m getting  a consistant connectException : connection refused from one of the chips, this is the server class i m using in processing :
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class ServerHandler implements Runnable {
    private ServerSocket server;
    private boolean serverRunning = true;
    private String receivedMessage = null;
    private int port;
    private boolean isConfigserver;
    private ExecutorService clientThreadPool;
    private int clientCounter = 0;

    public ServerHandler(int port, boolean isConfigserver) {
        this.port = port;
        this.isConfigserver = isConfigserver;
        this.clientThreadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Create a server socket to listen on the specified port
            server = new ServerSocket(this.port);
            println("Server is running on port : " + this.port);
            
            while (serverRunning) {
                try {     
                    Socket client = server.accept(); // Accept incoming connections
                    clientCounter++;
                    println("Client connected: " + client.getInetAddress() + ", Total clients handled: " + clientCounter);

                    if (!isConfigserver) {
                        // Handle each client connection in a separate thread
                        ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(client, selectedMode, Nombre_mesures);
                        clientThreadPool.submit(clientHandler);
                    } else {
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                        String receivedData = reader.readLine();
                        if (receivedData != null) {
                            receivedData = receivedData.trim();
                            println("Received from Arduino about config: " + receivedData);
                            if (receivedData.equals("OK")) {
                                isReady = true;
                                //println("we are ready to go");
                            }
                        }
                        client.close();
                        println("Client connection closed after configuration");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    println("Error handling client connection: " + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            println("Server error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopServer() {
        serverRunning = false;
        if (server != null && !server.isClosed()) {
            try {
                server.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                println("Error closing server: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        clientThreadPool.shutdown();
    }

    private class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
        private Socket client;
        private String selectedMode;
        private int Nombre_mesures;
        private int counter_requete = 0;

        public ClientHandler(Socket client, String selectedMode, int Nombre_mesures) {
            this.client = client;
            this.selectedMode = selectedMode;
            this.Nombre_mesures = Nombre_mesures;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                println("Handling client: " + client.getInetAddress());
                try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()))) {
                    if (!mode_auto) {
                        while (counter_requete < Nombre_mesures) {
                            String receivedData = reader.readLine();
                            if (receivedData != null) {
                                receivedData = receivedData.trim();
                                println("Received from Arduino: " + receivedData);
                                // extractAndWriteData(receivedData, selectedMode, counter_requete);
                                counter_requete++;
                                println("Current request counter: " + counter_requete);
                            }
                        }
                        counter_requete = 0;
                    } else {
                        if (compteur_auto < Nombre_mesures * combinations1280.size() * gatewayList.size()) {
                            String receivedData = reader.readLine();
                            if (receivedData != null) {
                                receivedData = receivedData.trim();
                                println("Received from Arduino: " + receivedData);
                                extractAndWriteData(receivedData, selectedMode, counter_requete);
                                compteur_auto++;
                                ismesuredone = true;
                                delay(300);
                                // println("Automatic mode counter: " + compteur_auto);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    println("Error reading client data: " + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        client.close();
                        println("Client connection closed");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        println("Error closing client connection: " + e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                println("Unhandled exception: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void delay(int ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            println("Delay interrupted: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

this server class runs in it own thread as a way to handle response from arduinos chips, as for how a connection is iniatialised, in  the main code  i do this :
for (int i = 0; i < gatewayList.size(); i++) {
    int index = gatewayList.get(i);
    int[] firstIP = ipAddresses.get(index);
    String adress_GW = firstIP[0] + "." + firstIP[1] + "." + firstIP[2] + "." + firstIP[3];
   // println(adress_GW);

     int retryCount = 0;
    int maxRetries = 5; // Limit the number of retries to avoid infinite loops

   while (!isSent && retryCount < maxRetries) {
        try {
            myClient = new Client(this, adress_GW, 80);
            if (myClient.active()) {
                myClient.write(message);
                isSent = true;
                println("Message sent to " + adress_GW);
            } else {
                println("Client is not active, retrying...");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            println("Exception: " + e.getMessage() + ", retrying... (" + (retryCount + 1) + "/" + maxRetries + ")");
        } finally {
            retryCount++;
            delay(200); // Delay before retrying
        }
    }

    if (!isSent) {
        println("Failed to send message to " + adress_GW + " after " + maxRetries + " retries.");
    }
    isSent = false;
  
      }

where i send a message to each gateway, 3 of the 4 gateway got the message , but the last one consistanly give me this :
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:593)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:507)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:287)
    at processing.net.Client.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at G4P_interface.automatique_window_draw(G4P_interface.java:1335)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at g4p_controls.GWindow.draw(Unknown Source)
    at g4p_controls.GWindowAWT.draw(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2094)
    at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$9.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1386)
    at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:356)

any suggestions why this occur ? why the connection was refused ?
i tried to add connection timeout, retry and further investigate the exception but didn't find the reason this occured.
